# Does $a_n \le b_n \implies \lim a_n \le \lim b_n$ hold?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

For two sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ with $a_n\le b_n,\forall n \in\mathbb{N}$, it is true that $\lim a_n \le \lim b_n$, right?
I need this result to prove something but I can not find it  anywhere.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But note that even if for every $n\in \Bbb{N}$ we have $a_n< b_n$, we might end up with $\lim a_n \leq \lim b_n$ i.e strict inequality could become a weak one in the limit.

Comment: @peek-a-boo thansk!

Comment: To be more rigorous, you need to state both $a_n$ and $b_n$ have limits.

Answer (score 2):

Two cases, suppose that $\lim b_{n}= \infty$, then the result holds. So suppose that $\lim b_{n} \leq \infty$. Let $L_a$ and $L_b$ denote the two limits respectively.

Suppose that $L_a > L_b$. Let $0<\epsilon< L_a -L_b$. Now there exist an $N_{1}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N_1$, $ |a_n-L_a|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Similarly an $N_{2}$ such that $|b_n - L_b|< \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n\geq N_2$. Thus by construction we have that for all $n \geq min(N_1,N_2)$ that
$$
\begin{align}
b_{n} &< L_b + \frac{\epsilon}{2} \\
&<L_a - \frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
& < a_n
\end{align}
$$
but that contradicts the assumption that $a_{n} \leq b_{n}$.

Comment: Thanks, But I have proved this for myself!

Comment: @Xenusi Then why do you ask this question?

Comment: @Surb Because I was doing an assignment, and I assumed it was the case. Since I can not find it in the textbook I drop using that fact.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, $a_n=0$, because the difference of two limits is the limit of the differences (provided the limits exist). Now the limit of a non-negative sequence cannot be negative.